# jQuery open default context menu of target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I have a standardised rounded-corners button following the format like

```
<a href="#"><span>button name</span></a>
```

(Example:Anchor for left rounded corner, span for right rounded corner)

Problem is in IE, the context menu is that of the span tag and not the anchor, and hence I don't have the context menu option of opening up the parent link in new tab.

Is it possible to target the parent anchor and trigger it's context menu when I click on the span tag in IE?? I just want the browser default context menu, not a customised one.

(Works fine in FF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll close this question with the answer: No known possible solution.

But here is the solution to the root of the question/issue:
I'll try making the anchor the root element instead of the span.

That way, right click context menu will always have the option open in new tab for IE, whilst I can still keep the cross browser consistent (+dynamic width) rounded corners button. (Tried and tested)

Comment: Unless you plan on marking this as the accepted answer, this should be an edit to your original question, or at least a comment.

Comment: Ok, edited answer to close this thread. Will tick when stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `<span>`, and use CSS to provide rounded corners on the anchor elements. This will [make your HTML more semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729447/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-semantic-html), and provide graceful degradation in browsers that don't support CSS rounded corners (read: IE).

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="rounded">button name</a>
```

#### CSS

```
a.rounded {
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: @Brandon: what doesn't work? Rendering rounded corners? I know it doesn't.

Comment: Many ppl. still using IE7, I need to make sure it looks right as per design. (I'm not really for graceful degradation in this scenario)

Comment: I understand your solution, but the answer is "not possible" to the question?