# can i use Href on li b?

Tags: css, href, navbar, image-replacement

[preview of website homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFqnJ.jpg)

my first problem is that the link wont work for li b

is this something impossible?

I want to move the navbuttons down to align with the logo.
Also, I want to change the logo img for every navbutton (see img)

```
<ul>

  <li><a href="home"><img src='images/logo1.jpg' width='550 height='400' onmouseover="this.src='images/logo.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/logo1.jpg';" /></a></li>
  <li><b href="music"><img src='images/m.jpg'/></b></li>
  <li><b href="news"><img src='images/j.jpg'/></b></li>
  <li><b href="contact"><img src="images/s.jpg"/></b></li>
  <li><b href="about"><img src="images/g.jpg"/></b></li>
  <li><b href="contact"><img src="images/p.jpg"/></b></li>
  <li><b href="about"><img src="images/c.jpg"/></b></li>
</ul>


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;}
li {
    float: left;}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;}

li b {
    display: block;
    padding: 280px 0px 0px 0px ;
    text-decoration: none;}

li b:hover{
```

Hope someone can help, though i am really noob still

Comment: No... `b` does not understand `href` attribute. Just make it separate: `<b><a href=...>xxx</a></b>`. For details, read the online HTML documentation at http://www.w3.org.

Comment: There you can see the attributes that B can have: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp

Comment: Thank you, that works, ofcourse. been going at it for a while and guess i mixed stuff up.

Answer (score 2):

`href` is what's known as an "attribute". Elements (like `<a>` and `<b>`) define and support their own attributes, so you can't just use an attribute that "works" with one element and use it on another. That said, some attributes, like `class`, have nearly universal support (meaning they are supported by almost all elements).

The short answer to your question is "no"... the `<b>` element does not support the `href` attribute.

You can, however, wrap most elements in an `<a>` tag to turn it into a link, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><b>Go To Google</b></a>
```

Note that the `href` attribute must be a URL or URI if you want the link to actually work. `home` is not a URL, and thus the link won't work as you'd expect. See MDN's ["What is a URL?"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL) for more information.

For future reference, check out [MDN's HTML element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). There, you will find a complete list of elements and the attributes they support.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and i will look into that.

Comment: I'd recommend you avoid w3.org. A lot of their tutorials are buggy and the documentation is incomplete or outright incorrect. [MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is much more thorough and is generally easier to understand (especially for beginners).

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use href with b.

As per the mdn reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

which says standard attributes only, which are stated here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

I would suggest converting all your b tags to a. If you want to style them to look like b, you can do so using css.

Using the right html element for designed purpose is a best practice.

Please see [What are the benefits of using semantic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729447/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-semantic-html)