# best practice for show News list in html5

Tags: css, html

In my page i need to list last news with title only. I have two methods:

One:

```
<div>
  <p>Title One</p>
  <p>Title Two</p>
  <p>Title Three</p>
  <p>Title .....</p>
  <p>Title .....</p>
  <p>Title .....</p>
</div>
```

Two:

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li>TTILE ONE </li>
     <li>TTILE Two </li>
     <li>TTILE THree</li>
     <li>TTILE .....</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In HTML5 which way is better and readable?! with `<p></p>` Or `<ul><li>`?!

Comment: Neither is better in terms of hot html can be read. However it is considered a list, and so your question can be answered by means of using <li>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is better in terms of how html can be read. However it is considered a list, and so your question can be answered by means of using `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

You have there a list of news, so the correct one is `UL`.

The first option, using paragraphs is bad, because... Do you thing titles are paragraphs? I think title != paragraph, so uou can't use `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using an unordered list, `<ul>`, would be more [semantically correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294493/what-does-semantically-correct-mean) than using a paragraph, `<p>`.

Obviously either one could be used, so semantics may feel like a 6 vs half dozen sort of thing,  but in the long run using the correct tags will make your job easier.

The `<p>` will come with native styles, i.e. margins and so on, that will need to be removed in your css if you intend you use them this way. While `<ul>` and `<li>` will probably only need to have bullet points accounted for.

Also not everyone experiences the web in the same way, try to keep in mind that screen readers will take markup into account when reading pages to the visually impaired.

In more extreme cases semantics can even effect your search engine optimization (SEO). Google, for instance, may grab your first paragraph and use it as a part of your site description.