# JQuery mouseover is called - but can't change any CSS element

Tags: jquery

I have a small test website with two DIVS of class "gc-navbar-btn". See image:
[image]

I've been trying to change the background to black when the mouse hovers. I know the mouseover function is called as my "alert" test works. But nothing I do has any effect on the "backgroundColor" (also tried "background-color", "background") nothing works. no effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.gc-navbar-btn').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': '#000000'}, 300); <<---- DOES NOTHING
    alert("test");  <-- WORKS- REACHES HERE!

});

$('.gc-navbar-btn').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({'background-color': 'transparent'}, 300);

});

});
```

Comment: Protip: You should use `<button>` for button-like elements with few exceptions.

Comment: Protip2: Use CSS instead of jQuery

Comment: I know. but this is really experimental code -- forget this is a button -- this is a DIV that needs to animate its background color when hovered on. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: By default jQuery animate doesn't support colors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add jquery-ui.js library, for color animation

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.gc-navbar-btn').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      color: '#FFFFFF',
    }, 300);
    //alert("test");

});

$('.gc-navbar-btn').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
      'background-color': 'transparent',
      color: '#000000'
    }, 300);

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="gc-navbar-btn">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Guys, why are you flagging this down? Isn't it what I needed (adding jquery-ui) it worked perfectly when I added it to my code.

Comment: Give a man a hammer, and he can fish for a day... Teach him CSS and he can make animating background colors all day long.

Comment: I understand and prefer CSS -- but can it work on older browsers such as IE8?

Comment: I'm using JQuery 1.9 -- it's a prerequisite that what I do has to work on older browsers as well.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```css
.gc-navbar-btn {
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: blue;
      transition: background-color 1000ms;
    }

    .gc-navbar-btn:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="gc-navbar-btn"></div>
```

Comment: OP would probably want to transition on this change.

Comment: You should add a bit more explanation rather than just code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to do this with JS? You could use this css for this task and it would be far more [semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294493/what-does-semantically-correct-mean):

```css
.gc-navbar-btn {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Make the color fade slowly instead of suddenly (modern browsers only) */
  transition: background-color: 3000ms;
}
.gc-navbar-btn:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="gc-navbar-btn">Login</button>
<button class="gc-navbar-btn">Sign Up</button>
```

If you really need to use JS (and as far as I can tell, you don't) the issue is that you're trying to use animate to change a color gradually and jQuery alone doesn't do that. You'd need a [plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/**).

Comment: How new does a browser have to be to support this? will IE8 work with this?

Comment: But please be aware, unless you HAVE to support ie8 (and I'm sorry if you do) you **shouldn't**. It's dieing, let it. http://www.theie8countdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was missing something :

jquery-ui.min.js

I only used the query minimum...

once added -- it started working.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but this really isn't how you should do this.

Answer (score 0):

By default `jQuery.animate()` doesn't support color transitions. There are several plug-ins that add this feature to jQuery for example [jQuery.color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) or [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

In the following example I used jQuery.color

```js
$('.gc-navbar-btn').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': '#000000', 'color': '#FFFFFF'}, 300);

});

$('.gc-navbar-btn').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({'background-color': 'transparent', 'color':'#000000'}, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="gc-navbar-btn">Login</div>
```