# css for html table, to have one column's width automatic based on its content and all others equal

Tags: css, html-table

I need to migrate a table structure created with CSS grid to an html `<table>` structure.

The CSS grid layout is

```
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr 1fr
```

How can I accomplish the same result using an HTML table element, with appropriate `table`, `tr`, `td` etc CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`grid-template-columns` would be applied to each `<tr>` and `table, tbody, td {display: block}` added as well. This should work as long as each `<tr>` has a maximum of 4 `<td>` or there is only one `<tr>` that contains all of the `<td>`. Below are examples of both table structures. Note the presence of `<tbody>` is implicit since  browsers will insert one within a `<table>` if it's not in the HTML.

```css
table,
tbody,
td {
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


/* Not Required */

.A {
  background: tomato;
}

.B {
  background: yellow;
}

.C {
  background: cyan;
}

.D {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<!-- Original Grid Structure 4x3 -->
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='A'>A</div>
  <div class='B'>B</div>
  <div class='C'>C</div>
  <div class='D'>D</div>
  <div class='A'>A</div>
  <div class='B'>B</div>
  <div class='C'>C</div>
  <div class='D'>D</div>
  <div class='A'>A</div>
  <div class='B'>B</div>
  <div class='C'>C</div>
  <div class='D'>D</div>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- Traditional Table Structure 4x3 -->
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='grid'>
      <td class='A'>A</td>
      <td class='B'>B</td>
      <td class='C'>C</td>
      <td class='D'>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='grid'>
      <td class='A'>A</td>
      <td class='B'>B</td>
      <td class='C'>C</td>
      <td class='D'>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='grid'>
      <td class='A'>A</td>
      <td class='B'>B</td>
      <td class='C'>C</td>
      <td class='D'>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<!-- Table Structure 12x1 -->
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='grid'>
      <td class='A'>A</td>
      <td class='B'>B</td>
      <td class='C'>C</td>
      <td class='D'>D</td>
      <td class='A'>A</td>
      <td class='B'>B</td>
      <td class='C'>C</td>
      <td class='D'>D</td>
      <td class='A'>A</td>
      <td class='B'>B</td>
      <td class='C'>C</td>
      <td class='D'>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately in the "Traditional table structure" solution, each row is an independent grid, so depending on the first td's content in each row the columns width would be different.

Comment: @user2520818 The 2nd table would work visually, but not [semantically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1294493/2813224).